# What does the "WARN: Crawling Stopped" warning mean?

Tags: logging

Why do my logs fill up with warnings about Crawling Stopped?

Is this indicating some sort of problem that I need to address?

```
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=sitecore_core_index] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=sitecore_master_index] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=sitecore_web_index] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=sitecore_solr_analytics_index] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=sitecore_core_index_solr] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=sitecore_master_index_solr] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=sitecore_web_index_solr] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=ac_products_master_index] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=ac_products_web_index] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=sitecore_testing_index] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=sitecore_suggested_test_index] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=sitecore_fxm_master_index] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=sitecore_fxm_web_index] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=sitecore_fxm_domains_master] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=sitecore_fxm_domains_web] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=sitecore_list_index] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=social_messages_master] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=social_messages_web] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=sitecore_core_index] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=sitecore_master_index] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=sitecore_web_index] Crawling Stopped
5088 00:00:01 WARN  [Index=sitecore_solr_analytics_index] Crawling Stopped
```

Comment: Has indexing been paused and not resumed?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: You can shut the application down and let it start up fresh. My guess is that some operation paused or stopped indexing and it was never started again.

Comment: Check the index files for a 'write.lock' file. When an index is being updated this file locks the index to prevent other processes from interfering. If an index process is prevented from completing this file will never be removed. You may need to delete the index and re-build it if this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Indexing has stopped & log entries are triggered from 'StopIndexing' method as shown.

[image: Crawling stopped message]

**Some Info:**

Check your Sitecore context log file has entries like **'WARN  Sitecore shutting down'**.This might interrupt the indexing process.
For More info please follow this [link](http://www.symsoftsolutions.com/Blog/List/Index-Rebuild-Stops-Abruptly-in-Sitecore)

Comment: Why is it stopping?

Comment: From log all indexes are stopped & was there any app pool recycle at the time of indexing     interruption

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: All indexes stopped at the same time and the timing in the logs suggests a app pool recycle. Please check automatic app pool recycles in IIS.

Comment: Make sure that the keepalive is working so the app doesn't shut itself down. http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/what-is-the-purpose-of-keepalive-aspx